# Find a basis for $W$, where $W=\{(x_1,...,x_5)\in \mathbb{R}^5 : x_1=3x_2+x_3, x_2=x_5, \text{ and }x_4=2x_3\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Could you give me a hint in this exercise.

Get $W$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^5$ definite.
$$W=\{(x_1,...,x_5)\in \mathbb{R}^5 : x_1=3x_2+x_3, x_2=x_5, \text{ and }x_4=2x_3\}$$
Find a basis for $W$.

Comment: How many variables are free? i.e. What is the minimum number of variables you need to pick to recover all the others via those relations?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Note that a arbitrary vector of $W$ it seems $$v=\begin{pmatrix}3x_{2}+x_{3}\\ x_{2} \\ x_{3}\\ 2x_{3} \\x_{2}\\ \end{pmatrix}\in W$$where $x_{2},x_{3}\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: $x_2(3,1,0,0,1)+x_3(1,0,1,2,0)$?

Comment: Yes, You're right! So, $B=\{(3,1,0,0,1),(1,0,1,2,0)\}$ is  a basis for $W$.